# How to properly secure asp.net core 3.1 app from XSS attack and display HTML using @Html.Raw()

Tags: xss, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an `Asp.Net Core 3.1` razor page app. I'm receiving `HTML` content from user and that will be displayed back in the browser. It's kind of blog like app where my end user will be given a `WYSIWYG` editor and then the `HTML` from user will be encoded and saved in database.

Now when the blog page is requested, I need to decode the `HTML` content back and display in browser. This make my site vulnerable to `XSS` attack.

Here is my `HTML` from user,

```html
<p>blog 5</p><script>alert()</script>
```

I encode this and save in database,

```cs
&lt;p&gt;blog 5&lt;/p&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert()&lt;/script&gt;
```

Now to render the same,

```
@Html.Raw(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Blog.Content))
```

When the page gets rendered it shows javascript `alert()` box.

if I don`t decode then html string is displayed,

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Blog.Content)
```

as shown below,

```html
<p>blog 5</p><script>alert()</script>
```

I'm confused. Am I doing something wrong here? Please assist and correct me. I need the html to be safe and also it has to display as html in browser than as html string output.

Comment: No web framework has an easy answer for this. You need to scrub the user input which is almost impossible given the number of different encoding schemes. This is why most sites (like StackOverflow) don't allow unfettered HTML and instead support a subset like Markdown.

Comment: so the better way is to go for Markdown based editor?

Comment: A Markdown editor would definitely be better than accepting raw HTML but you still need to put in safegaurds. I think I've seen some blog post from SO about trusting user input. Google around I'm sure you'll find lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an HTML sanitizer library.  One of the more popular ones for .NET is:

https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

It is available on Nuget:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/

This will allow you to whitelist the tags that you want to allow.  See the wiki for additional documentation and examples.

Comment: This looks great